# Creating proportion table NAs included

Tags: r

If I have a table such as:

```
cc = c("i", "am", "useless", 0, 2, 4, 5)
aa = c("red", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "green", "green")
bb = c(1, 1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 0)
data <- data.frame(aa, bb, cc)
> data
     aa bb      cc
1   red  1       i
2  blue  1      am
3   red  0 useless
4   red NA       0
5  blue  1       2
6 green  1       4
7 green  0       5
```

and I just wanted something like

```
       propOf1
red    1/3
blue   1
green  1/2
```

where essentially I'm just getting the proportion of '1' relative to the whole population size of each unique category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr`.  You group by `aa` then you summarise the number of 1 divided by the total count `n()`.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(aa) %>% summarise(propOf1 = sum(bb=="1",na.rm = T)/n())
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  aa    propOf1
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 blue  1.00 
#2 green 0.500
#3 red   0.333
```

Answer (score 0):

With base R you may run

```
with(data, tapply(!is.na(bb) & bb == 1, data$aa, mean, na.rm = TRUE))
#      blue     green       red 
# 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data$bb[is.na(data$bb)] <- 0
aggregate(data$bb, by = list(data$aa), FUN = function(x) sum(x)/length(x))
```